# Passing an array to a method

Tags: java

So I have two files, this is the first one:

```
public class AnnualFuelUseTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnualFuelUse[] car = {new AnnualFuelUse(1, 1, 3023, 3070, 0.94, 3),
            new AnnualFuelUse(2, 3, 3070, 4224, 24.04, 2.21), new AnnualFuelUse(3, 2, 4224, 4292, 1.48, 2.10)};
        car.showOutput();
    }
}
```

and the second is:

```
public class AnnualFuelUse {
    public void showOutput(AnnualFuelUse[] car) {
        out.printf("%10s%10s%20s%20s%10s%20s%10s%10s%10s%n", "Fill Up", "Days", "Start Miles", "End Miles",
                "Distance", "Gallons Used", "MPG", "Price", "Cost");
        for(AnnualFuelUse car1 : car) {
            out.printf("%5d%5d%5d%5d%5d%5.2f%5.2f%5.2f%5.2f%n", car1.fillup, car1.days, car1.startMiles,
                    car1.endMiles, car1.distance, car1.gallonsUsed, car1.mpg, car1.price, car1.cost);
        }
        calcMinMax(car);
        calcAnnualProjection(car);
    }
```

I have a couple private variables and another couple methods but I think what I showed makes it pretty clear.  For some reason, I'm getting an error saying cannot resolve method `showOutput()` and tbh I don't know why, the files are in the same directory, everything is public and car is a `AnnualFuelUse[]`.

Comment: What do you think `car.showOutput();` should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: `car.showOutput();` should be `AnnualFuelUse c = new AnnualFuelUse(); c.showOutput(car);`

Comment: it is unfortunate that showOutput() is not static. This way you need a instance of AnnualFuelUse, even when you only want to print the given array. so make it static (and of course pass `car` to it. Minor nit: usually I make collections and array variables plural (cars).

Comment: thanks a ton @eckes, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over car and call showOutput() on each.

Comment: That's what I was worried about D:  Can you explain why abit? showOutput is supposed to take an array of AnnualFuelUse objects.  Is it because I have to call it from a object?

Comment: You can do AnualFuelUse::showOutput(car). This way you are passing in the array like you wanted.